# Infix to postfix converter not working

Tags: c++

```
      int prec(char ch)
     {
             switch (ch){
            case '/': 
            case '*': return 2;
            case '+':
            case '-': return 1;
            default: return 0;
     }

  }


    void infix_postfix(char infix[], char postfix[], int size)
    {
            stackType<char, 20> s;
            stack<char> s;
            int precedence;
            int i = 0;
            int k = 0;
            char ch;


    while (i < size)
    {
            ch = infix[i];
            //push the open parenthesis              
            if(ch =='(')
            {           
                    s.Push(ch);
                    i++;
                    continue;
            }
            //if a closed parenthesis is encountered, then pop all the elements and append it to the postfix expression till we encounter an open parenthesis                
            if(ch == ')')
            {

                    while(!s.isEmpty() && s.Top() != '(')
                    {

                            postfix[k++] = s.Top();
                            s.pop();
                    }

                    if (!s.isEmpty())
                    {
                            s.pop();
                    }
                    i++;
                    continue;
            }
            precedence = prec(ch);
            //If we encounter an operand then append it to the postfix expression             
            if (precedence = 0)
            {

                    postfix[k++] = ch;
            }
            else

                    if(s.isEmpty())
                    {
                     //push the operator onto the stack if stack is empty                             
                            s.Push(ch);
                    }
                    else
                    {
                    //pop all the operators from the stack and append it to the postfix expression till we see an operator with a lower precedence of the current operator
                            while(!s.isEmpty() && s.Top() != '(' && precedence < prec(s.Top()))
                            {

                                    postfix[k++] = s.Top();
                                    s.pop();
                            }

                    s.Push(ch);
                    }
            i++;
            }
            if(ch == ')')
            //if a closed parenthesis is encountered, then pop all the elements and append it to the postfix expression till we encounter an open parenthesis
            {

                    while(!s.isEmpty() && s.Top() != '(')
                    {

                            postfix[k++] = s.Top();
                            s.pop();
                    }

                    if (!s.isEmpty())
                    {
                            s.pop();
                    }
                    i++;
                    continue;
            }
            while (!s.isEmpty())
            {
                    postfix[k++] = s.Top();
                    s.pop();
            }
            s.Push(ch);
            postfix[k] = 0; 

       }
  int main()
  {
    char infix[] = "a*(b+c)";
    int size = strlen(infix);
    char postfix[size];
    infix_postfix(infix, postfix, size);
    cout << "Infix Expression is: " << infix << endl;
    cout << "Postfix Expression is: " << postfix;
    cout << endl;
    return 0;
   }
```

When I execute this code, it does not properly place the letter and the operators in the right order. It seems that the operator comes first rather than the operands and the order is changed even more when I put a open parenthesis in the middle of the infix expression. For example, when I put a+(b+c) as the infix expression, the result ends ups as +cb+a.

Comment: At first glance, Switch Case would return `1` for +

Comment: `if (precedence = 0)` should be `if (precedence == 0)`.